# How can I place an empty box on the branches of this tree diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]

% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{bag} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {Bag 1 $4W, 3B$}
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2 $4W, 5B$}        
                child {
                    node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(W_1\cap W_2)=\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{9}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$W$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{4}{9}$}
            }
                child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(W_1\cap B_2)=\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{5}{9}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$B$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{5}{9}$}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[above] {$W$}
            node[below]  {$\frac{4}{7}$}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2 $3W, 6B$}        
        child {
            node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(B_1\cap W_2)=\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{3}{9}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$B$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{3}{9}$}
                }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(B_1\cap B_2)=\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{6}{9}$}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$W$}
                node[below]  {$\frac{6}{9}$}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$B$}
            node[below]  {$\frac{3}{7}$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The attached MWE is taken from the tikz example website.
I would like to replace the probabilities on each branch with a box.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the text from the nodes and add `draw,minimum size=1cm`?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the source? The 'tikz example website' is (1) huge and (2) potentially meaningless to those not 'in the know'. Does your editor really save your documents in `latin1` encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Adapations:**

- I defined a command `\emptybox` to create the box inside the text (after the equation sign) at the leaves of the tree.
- I defined a style `ebox` with: `ebox/.style={below=1mm, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=6mm, draw}`.
- Use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/123129)).
- I swapped `B` and `W` at the top branch.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzset{
    % Set the overall layout of the tree
    level 1/.style={level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm},
    % Define styles for bags and leafs
    bag/.style={text width=4em, text centered},
    end/.style={circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt}
}

\newcommand{\emptybox}{\fbox{\parbox[c][8mm]{20mm}{\ }}}

% The sloped option gives rotated edge labels. Personally
% I find sloped labels a bit difficult to read. Remove the sloped options
% to get horizontal labels. 
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped,
    ebox/.style={below=1mm, minimum width=10mm, minimum height=6mm, draw}
]

\node[bag] {Bag 1 $4W, 3B$}
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2 $4W, 5B$}        
                child {
                    node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(W_1\cap W_2)=$ \emptybox}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$W$}
                node[ebox]  {}
            }
                child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(W_1\cap B_2)=$ \emptybox}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$B$}
                node[ebox]  {}
            }
            edge from parent 
            node[above] {$W$}
            node[ebox]  {}
    }
    child {
        node[bag] {Bag 2 $3W, 6B$}        
        child {
            node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(B_1\cap W_2)=$ \emptybox}] {} %
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$W$}
                node[ebox]  {}
                }
            child {
                node[end, label=right:
                    {$P(B_1\cap B_2)=$ \emptybox}] {}
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$B$}
                node[ebox]  {}
            }
        edge from parent         
            node[above] {$B$}
            node[ebox]  {}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

Comment: @cfr Ok, I know. I changed it now.